# Positioning y axis and node near coords

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

What I obtained:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Operations needed:

- Positioning `y axis` on Zero
- Anchoring `node near coords` on the right side of the blue line

The code I used is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{RR.dat}
y   x   Label
2   116.6   MT600
3   -17.43  SC600
4   17.6    TC700
\end{filecontents*}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines*=left,
        yticklabels from table={RR.dat}{Label},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\thenumber{}},
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x} \as \thenumber},
        ]
        \addplot+[xcomb] table [x=x, y=y] {RR.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new column for shifting the nodes near coordniates since these have to be shifted non-uniformly. I did it with `shift` column and added values accordingly. Then add the following lines:

   ```
   visualization depends on={value \thisrow{shift}\as\myshift},
   every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\myshift},
   ```
2. Use `axis y line*=middle,` so that y axis is drawn at `x=0`.
3. Move the y tick labels to left using `yticklabel style={xshift=-8mm},`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{RR.dat}
y   x   Label     shift
2   116.6   MT600    0
3   -17.43  SC600    8mm
4   17.6    TC700    0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=middle,
        yticklabels from table={RR.dat}{Label},
        ytick=data,
        yticklabel style={xshift=-8mm},
        nodes near coords={\thenumber{}},
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{shift}\as\myshift},
        every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\myshift},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x} \as \thenumber},
        ]
        \addplot+[xcomb,mark=square*] table [x=x, y=y] {RR.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Instead of adding a new column I modified your solution:   `visualization depends on={value 2.1cm*(-\thisrow{x}+max(0,\thisrow{x})) \as \myshift},
  every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\myshift},`